# How can I add an entry to an existing my.ini file for a mysql service with the command line?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to append an existing my.ini with a new configuration via the command line. I need to add the line 'event_scheduler=ON' to the my.ini file during an install.  I will have the root password if the is necessary.  I thought I might be able to use the mysql command line app to manipulate the .ini file, but haven't been able to find anything about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have privileges to edit the ini file, you can do this using any text editor (try `nano` if you know nothing about non-GUI text editors). If you just want to append a single line, you could also do `echo "text to append" >> my.ini` which will append the specified text on its own line.

(caution: using `>` instead of `>>` will overwrite the file instead...).